# how to daemonize Rails Rake task on Elastic Beanstalk start up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk web server environment called "my-env".  I want my-env to execute the following bash command on start up:  `bundle exec rake jobs:work`.  I am new to EB and my Bash is mediocre (at best).  I flailed about all day yesterday and came up with the following which works, `.ebextensions/start_worker.config`:

***Edit:*** Actually, the following isn't working correctly.  It seems to work properly initially then starts generating errors.  Perhaps the environment changes?

```
commands:
  create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true
files:
  "/usr/sbin/jobs_worker.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars
      export PATH=/home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.1.2/bin:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bin:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
      cd $EB_CONFIG_APP_CURRENT
      su -c "RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake jobs:work" $EB_CONFIG_APP_USER
      echo "worker starting" >> /var/log/directory-hooks-executor.log    
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_restart_delayed_job.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      nohup /usr/sbin/jobs_worker.sh 0<&- &> /var/log/directory-hooks-executor.log &
```

So this creates a script in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post` so EB executes it automatically when I deploy.  I had to daemonize so that the script wouldn't hold up EB's start up sequence.

So I doubt that this is going to work well in the long run.  I would appreciate any advice on how this could be done cleaner; perhaps by means of a linux service, or within a Rails initializer.  Also I would like to know if there is a danger that this script will be run more than once or stop unexpectedly.  So I guess I am asking for any general advise on how I could best proceed from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have found a suitable solution.  I installed the ruby gem: "daemons" and switched the script to:

```
commands:
  create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true
  webapp_pids:
    command: "mkdir /home/webapp/pids"
    ignoreErrors: true
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_restart_delayed_job.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars
      chown webapp:webapp /home/webapp/pids
      su -l -c "$EB_CONFIG_APP_CURRENT/bin/delayed_job --pid-dir=/home/webapp/pids restart" $EB_CONFIG_APP_USER
      echo "worker starting" >> /var/log/directory-hooks-executor.log
```

So far seems to be working.

Comment: Scripts in /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/ will be executed during every application version deployment. As long as you gracefully handle restarts of your script it shuld be fine.