# How to run a long running job on Amazon EC2 instance in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, resque, job-scheduling

I'm using resque gem, and I'm running the jobs through the following command:

```
rake resque:work QUEUE='*'
```

But the problem is: As my SSH connection with remote server gets disconnected, or I close the SSH session window that is running the process `rake resque:work QUEUE='*'`, it stops running the job.

I'd like to have a way in which the job will run independently: no need to remain connected with through SSH. Is there a way, or should I follow this procedure to accomplish what I require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can run rake task in background. There are multiple ways to accomplish this. Two of them are here:

1. Using daemon you can run a rake task in background. Here is [link](http://www.linfo.org/daemon.html) for what is daemon. Here is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555715/daemoninsing-a-rake-task), How to achieve this for rails rake tasks. Appending `&` to rake task is my preferred way.
2. Implement a cron to run rake task individually.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this thing: do I need to have *whenever* gem to run a cron easily?

Comment: Yes you need whenever to setup cron on server. didn't you try `rake resque:work QUEUE='*' &`. This is what you should run.

Comment: For proper solution you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260733/how-to-daemonize-rails-rake-task-on-elastic-beanstalk-start-up .

Answer (score 3):

One more way to run task in background: `screen`. It creates as many shell sessions as you need, and they can be detached from your initial session. 
Run:

`screen` (you'll be in a new shell session)

`/path/to/your/script > /path/to/log_file`

Ctrl+A, Ctrl+D
(here you return to the initial shell session, whilst the session you started your script will continue to run)

You can watch progress by `tail -f /path/to/log_file`, log off and log on again. To return to the detached session run `screen -r`.

If you don't have `screen` installed run `yum install screen`. Unsure about Ubuntu, perhaps it'll be `apt-get install screen`. Run `man screen` for more details.